# LTspice inrush current simulation

Tags: ltspice, inrush-current

I'm trying to simulate the inrush current of a system that I measured with an oscilloscope before.
In my simulation I have a voltage bouncing effect on the wire between the supply and the Rshunt that I haven't with real life measurement.
What causes that bouncing effect?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! If you by bouncing mean the oscillation on the blue curve, it's from oscillation between C and L. You have several of them so I can't see directly which ones, but probe around and you should be able to find it. Try a 1 kohm resistor across each L to dampen it out. If L4.1 and L4.2 is supposed to form a CM choke, you need to provide a spice statement (press s) of k L4.1 L4.2 0.999.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few resonant sub-circuits made of L and C and the PWL input
excites them all.

Bouncing comes from one of the inductors that couples with one capacitor.
The oscillations you see comes from an LC resonant circuit that is weakly dumped by a resistor in the current path.

If L4.1 and L4.2 are a common mode filter you should add the coupling factor to refine your simulation.

A Common Mode Filter is composed by 2 inductors both wound on a Ferrite core. The two inductors are "coupled".

---

Filtering action of noisy currents by the Common Mode Filter:

If inductor 1 creates a magnetic flux, due to some noisy current, inductor 2 receives that flux thanks to the magnetic core.

Inductor 2 receives the flux and creates an opposite flux that is received by inductor 1, which in turns rejects the noisy current.

Comment: As you said I put a Spice directive k L4.1 L4.2 0.999.
All the oscillation are gone and the current is almost the as my real life measurement.

I'm quite new in electronic if someone can try to explain me why adding a coupling factor on both of the inductance solved the oscillations ?

Comment: @SteveninJ Because without it you have two huge inductors in series for your normal differential mode current. With it, they cancel out for differential mode but will filter for common mode instead.